# How to add xml block to original xml structure with python

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I am going to get the text from the textarea and change it to xml structure and insert to my original xml structure
Like this
text from textarea

```
<abc>
<tag>
some text
</tag>
</abc>
```

original structure

```
<content>
<item>
</item>
</content>
```

the result will be

```
<content>
<item>
<abc>
<tag>

some text

</tag>
</abc>
</item>
</content>
```

I tried in many ways but I got 
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: unbound prefix:
this error or other errors.
How can I make this work?

Comment: When you are not showing any of your code, nobody can help you. And this also means your *actual* XML, because "XML like this" is not precise enough.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30597100/parsing-xml-with-undeclared-prefixes-in-python
This answer solved my problem!!!

Comment: It would be quite easier to spot the issues with actual XML